# KeyPress event on combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combo box in a desktop application, I'm trying to give it a KeyPress action listener

here is the code I have

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int selectedIndex = combobox.SelectedIndex;
                if (selectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    switch (selectedIndex)
                    {
                        //.......
                    };
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I need to add it to the combobox, I try something like

```
this.combobox.KeyDown += new KeyEventArgs(this.comboBox1_KeyDown);
```

but it's not working.

Comment: 'ContinueBehaviour' is the name of your combobox?

Comment: yes it's the name of the combibox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a handler to an event, not some arguments. (Does it even compile?)

Instead of

```
this.combobox.KeyDown += new KeyEventArgs(this.comboBox1_KeyDown);
```

try

```
this.combobox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.comboBox1_KeyDown);
```

`KeyEventHandler` is in System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.KeyDown += comboBox1_KeyDown;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the compilation problem or not I think you should handle SelectedIndex with SelectedIndexChanged
event, because KeyDown
if fired before the SelectedIndex is changed.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in [connecting between **The Event Handler Method** and **The Event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/xwbwks95(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
this.combobox.KeyDown += new KeyEventArgs(this.comboBox1_KeyDown);
```

In the above line of code, you are using  `KeyEventArgs` as event handler method. But it is not an event handler method.

Instead, you should use `KeyEventHandler`, which is the corresponding  event handler method to handle the event.

**EventArgs**

`EventArgs` represents the base class for classes that contain event data, and provides a value to use for events that do not include event data.

The Instance of `EventArgs`, which contains the event data is used by Event Handler Method to do the actions based on the needs.

**KeyEventHandler**

`KeyEventHandler` is the method that will handle the `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event of a Control.

Similarly for `KeyPress` event, there is `KeyPressEventHandler` method.

So you should change your code to :

```
this.comboBox.KeyDown += 
                  new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.ComboBox_KeyDown);
```